# Bounded Laplacian and function implies bounded gradient

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, interpolation

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function. Suppose that in a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, we have two bounds:
$$
|f(x)|\leq A
$$
and
$$
|\Delta f(x)|\leq B
$$
Is it true that we have some bound of the form
$$
|\nabla f(x)|\lesssim A^\theta B^{1-\theta},
$$
where $x\in U$?

The one-dimensional case is easier to verify. But I wonder if there is some high dimensional analogue.

Comment: The more natural generalization uses the full second derivative/Hessian rather than the Laplacian - the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality) has as a special case $|\nabla f| \lesssim |f|_0^{1/2} |\nabla^2 f|_0^{1/2}$. I don't think you can improve this to use the Laplacian instead, since it's well known in elliptic PDE that you can't estimate the $C^2$ norm of $f$ in terms of the supremum of $|\Delta f|$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality cannot give us a pointwise (or $L^\infty$) bound, can it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exponents $p,q,r=\infty$ are allowed.

Comment: If $f$ is harmonic, you'd be saying $|\nabla f (x)| = 0?$

Comment: @zhw. thanks for your comment. Actually, Anthony mentioned that we must use the full Hessian to bound $\nabla f(x)$.